# Fixed background image keeps on moving

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a background image which I want to keep fixed in the top right corner. When I narrow the screen to see how the site looks on mobile the image moves. I don't want this to happen, I don't want it to show on mobile but to show on desktop.

My CSS...

```
body {
    font-family: Gafata;
    background: url("/static/TH1.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
}
```

So I change the attachment to fixed...

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

but the image looses it's position (moves left), so I add `background-position`...

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

and it starts moving with the browser again!!

Comment: Could you demonstrate with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to show on desktop and want to hide from mobile devices then add following css

**for Mobile**

```
body {
    font-family: Gafata;
    background: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
  }
```

**for desktop**

```
@media (min-weidth: 768px) {
  body {
    font-family: Gafata;
    background: url("/static/TH1.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
  }
}
```